# SageMaker update endpoint hangs and fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

We have a weekly job in Databricks that calls the following code to update a live SageMaker endpoint. The endpoint is hosted on 7 m4x.large instances and serves a fairly high amount of trafic (100s of requests per second).

```
import mlflow.sagemaker as mfs
logged_model = 'runs:/' + run_id + '/model'
image_ecr_url = "882336743852.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mlflow-pyfunc:1.18.0"
mfs.deploy(app_name='modelName', model_uri=logged_model, image_url=image_ecr_url, region_name=region, instance_count=DEFAULT_INSTANCE_COUNT, mode="replace")
```

We have recently noticed that many times the job fails with the following error:

```
"ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateEndpoint operation: Cannot update in-progress endpoint"
```

Furthermore we see a huge spike in 4XX errors from the endpoint. Based on the documentation there should be no service downtime with updates... even if the update fails, we would not expect downtime to production traffic.

Do you have any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: Did you monitor the corresponding Cloudformation stack in console? That should tell you where exactly it is going wrong. From first look it seems that mfs.deploy() is trying to update a Cloudformation stack whose status is 'In Progess' instead of 'Create Complete' or 'Update Complete'. Try using Sagemaker's native API to update the endpoint - if it succeeds then issue is with your script/mlflow, otherwise with Sagemaker.